# ERROR- Use of undefined constant root - assumed 'root'

Tags: php, mysql

Please can I get help for this problem

Here's the code:

```
if( $_GET["sender"] == "Ajax" )

require_once "../db/connector.php";

else if ( $_GET["sender"] == "Ajax5" )

require_once "../db/connector.php";

else
require_once "db/connector.php";

//require_once "db/dbclass.php";

$mysql = new Datalink(localhost,root,'','whatsapp_dbase');


$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Here's the Error Message

> Notice: Use of undefined constant root - assumed 'root' in C:\wamp\www\whatsapp\db\mobilefx.php on line 9
>   Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\whatsapp\db\mobilefx.php on line 11
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant localhost - assumed 'localhost' in C:\wamp\www\whatsapp\db\mobilefx.php on line 9
>   Notice: Undefined index: sender in C:\wamp\www\whatsapp\db\mobilefx.php on line 2

Comment: Strings like `localhost` and `root` need to be "quoted".... `'localhost'` and `'root'`

Comment: did you mean $root and $localhost by any chance ?

Comment: 'root' and 'localhost'

Answer (score 2):

Many problems in this code :

> Notice: Use of undefined constant root

Change :

```
$mysql = new Datalink(localhost,root,'','whatsapp_dbase');
```

To :

```
$mysql = new Datalink(localhost,'root','','whatsapp_dbase');
```

PHP is looking at root and thinks it's a constant because you didn't enclose it with quotes (or double quotes) to tell PHP it's a string.

Same goes for localhost :

> Notice: Use of undefined constant localhost

Change :

```
$mysql = new Datalink(localhost,'root','','whatsapp_dbase');
```

To :

```
$mysql = new Datalink('localhost','root','','whatsapp_dbase');
```

Other errors come up because you didn't check whether or not $_GET variables existed before using them.

This is a duplicate though, so I won't go into details, learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index).